# multiple imputation: error loading mi package

Tags: r

I am trying to load the `mi` package in R for multiple imputation but I get the error saying:

```
library(mi)

Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'mi', details:
  call: utils::packageDescription("mi", lib.loc = miLib)$Version
  error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mi’
```

can anyone help, please?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have the most recent version of R and that all of your packages are up to date?

Comment: I updated everything. Now, when I start RStudio I get the following error

Error: invalid version specification ‘NA’
In addition: Warning message:
In utils:::packageDescription(packageName, fields = "Version") :
  no package 'knitr' was found

Comment: Just to confirm,  You re-downloaded and installed the latest version of R, then updated Rstudio, then updated/reinstalled any required packages. Also in RStudio can you do anything or does this error prevent you from loading RStudio?

Comment: I now reinstalled all: R, RStudio and all packages. The error when starting RStudio does not appear anymore. 
When installing "mi" I get a warning: 
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
When loading "mi" I still get the following error: 
no package 'mi' was foundError: package or namespace load failed for ‘mi’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'mi', details:
  call: utils::packageDescription("mi", lib.loc = miLib)$Version
  error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: It sounds like you are failing to download the mi package from your CRAN mirror.  There​ are a verity of things that could cause this.  Including: network connection, proxy settings, a bad mirror url, and probably a few things I can't think of.  I would search for Rstudio http 404 error on install.package you should find several posts.

Comment: Hi, the mi package installs, but wont load. I think it happened after I run the command `options(mc.cores=2)` on my work computer. It seems to load on a different machine, so I will try to use that one. Thanks for you help.